# syntaxError:Unexpected Token A in Json at position 0

Tags: javascript, java, php, arrays, json

When I am trying to create manual orders from my opencart admin v2.3.0.2 admin panel after adding the product when I am filling the Payment details section in opencart and click next to proceed to add shipping details. this error pops up on my screen. And i am not able to create new orders or edit the old orders. I need immediate help. Thank you in advance.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON.

Comment: This is not json. This is just a vardump

Comment: this error means invalid JSON try too stringify you value

Comment: You should read the guidance on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) without a set Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE) code to work from, no-one will be able to help with your query.

Answer (score 1):

1. This isn't JSON.
2. The error `Unexpected token A` refers to the word `Array` in your payload. Your JSON parser is looking for a curly brace, which is the first character in a correctly formatted JSON object, but it's finding the character `A` for `Array` instead.

Delete the word `Array` and replace your parentheses `( )` with curly braces `{ }`.

Comment: Even replacing the parentheses with curly braces won't solve the issue. It would still be invalid JSON.